# How can I use stl iterators with Eigen?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, eigen3

I am trying to use the Library Eigen in a project and I have to sort a vector. I tried to follow the documentation and it says that the library should work in the predictable way with the STL iterators and algorithms https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html.
However when I try to run the following test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
int main()
{
    Eigen::Array4i v = Eigen::Array4i::Random().abs();
    std::cout << "Here is the initial vector v:\n" << v.transpose() << "\n";
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << "Here is the sorted vector v:\n" << v.transpose() << "\n";
    return 0;
 }
```

I get the two following errors:

```
error: ‘Eigen::Array4i’ {aka ‘class Eigen::Array<int, 4, 1>’} has no member named ‘begin’
9 | std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  |             ^~~~~
error: ‘Eigen::Array4i’ {aka ‘class Eigen::Array<int, 4, 1>’} has no member named ‘end’
9 | std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I tested it with gcc 9.1.0 and 7.4.0 and my version of Eigen is 3.3.4. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the library is in the usual location /usr/include. All the other functionality I tried seem to work properly.
Is it a well known bug, is it a compiler problem or is it a version problem?

Comment: the std algorithm `std::sort`  would work perfectly for an `std::vector` because the container class `std::vector` has a member function called `begin()`[more about begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) which returns an iterator to the beginning of the sequence container. vice versa for `end()`. hence code like `std::sort(myVec.begin(),myVec.end())` works as the sort function gets valid arguments i.e. 2 valid iterators. As the error states here `Eigen::Array4i`  does not have a .begin() and .end() functions hence std::sort does not work.

Comment: Please, check the documentation for `Eigen::Array4i` for member functions which can return iterators to first and last element of the container and use those functions instead of `.begin()` and `.end()`

Comment: You need to use the development version of Eigen (or the upcoming 3.4, as it says right at the top of the page you linked to): https://godbolt.org/z/kTKanM But it even works with g++ 4.6: https://godbolt.org/z/WJpyty

Comment: Thank you @chtz I totally missed that sentence. I will install that version to work then

Comment: @dorKKnight Your comment is not helpful. It is not obvious at all to find that information in the documentation. There is a long and complex inheritance hierarchy for `Array4i` which is difficult to analyze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to wait for the release of Eigen 3.4, you can use this:

```
std::sort(v.data(), v.data() + v.size());
```

The `.data()` method can replace the missing `.begin()`, but the `.end()` method must be constructed manually.